# emacs C# C Sharp mode on Linux: Flymake csc.exe error

Tags: c#, linux, emacs, mono

I'm running c-sharp-mode on

```
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.9) of 2014-09-30 on buildvm-10.phx2.fedoraproject.org
```

Attempting to load flymake mode, however, gives me the error:

```
Flymake: Failed to launch syntax check process 'csc.exe' with args (/t:module /nologo Action_flymake.cs): Seaching for program: no such file or directory, csc.exe. Flymake will be switched OFF.
```

It appears to be hard-coded to look for csc.exe, which looks like it's built for Windows.  Besides disappointment, this doesn't seem to be mentioned on any help site I can find. How can I get this to work on my Fedora 20 (Mono is installed and working fine)?